# Unable to let my script generate few values automatically to be used within payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script to get the html elements from a target page by sending two https requests subsequently. My script can does the thing flawlessly. However, I had to copy the four values from chrome dev tools to fill in the four keys within `payload` in order to send the final http requests to reach the target page. This is the ***[starting link](https://www.discoverqatar.qa/)*** and following are the description as to how I could reach the target page.

1. Click on the `Find Hotel` button (no need to change dates if `chek-out` date is by default at least one day longer than `check-in` date).
2. Tick the box like the image below and press the `Book Now` button just above it. Now, it should lead you to the target page automatically.
3. Upon reaching the target page titled as `Enter Guest Details`, parse the html elements from there

[image]

***I've tried with (working one):***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://booking.discoverqatar.qa/SearchHandler.aspx?'
second_url = 'https://booking.discoverqatar.qa/PassengerDetails.aspx?'

params = {
    'Module':'H','txtCity':'','hdnCity':'2947','txtHotel':'','hdnHotel':'',
    'fromDate':'05/11/2019','toDate':'07/11/2019','selZone':'','minSelPrice':'',
    'maxSelPrice':'','roomConfiguration':'2|0|','noOfRooms':'1',
    'hotelStandardArray':'63,60,54,50,52,51','CallFrom':'','DllNationality':'-1',
    'HdnNoOfRooms':'-1','SourceXid':'MTEzNzg=','mdx':''
}

payload = {
    'CallFrom':'MToxNjozOCBQTXxCMkN8MToxNjozOCBQTQ==',
    'Btype':'MToxNjozOCBQTXxBfDE6MTY6MzggUE0=',
    'PaxConfig':'MToxNjozOCBQTXwyfDB8MnwwfHwxOjE2OjM4IFBN',
    'usid':'MToxNjozOCBQTXxoZW54dmkzcWVnc3J3cXpld2lsa2ZwMm18MToxNjozOCBQTQ=='  
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url,params=params,headers={"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    res = s.get(second_url,params=payload,headers={
        "User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0",
        "Referer":r.url
        })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    print(soup)
```

In the above script I've copied and pasted the value of `CallFrom`,`Btype`,`PaxConfig` and `usid` from dev tools to use within `payload`.

> How can I fill in the values automatically to be used within payload?

Comment: Isn't Kamoo's answer sufficient? I think I could get results, following their instructions.

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, thanks for your intervention. Yeah, Kamoo's answer clarifies as to how I can get the results but I highly doubt I can implement it myself within the above script and that is the very reason I set the bounty to get a full-fledged answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm sure @Kamoo will provide code if asked.

Comment: @MITHU I updated my answer, please note that `Btype` might be a dynamic value corresponding to options chosen from the first step. `PaxConfig` might also be in a different format if passengers include children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Params sent to the second request is **Base64** encoded, after decode they are:

```
    'CallFrom':'1:16:38 PM|B2C|1:16:38 PM',
    'Btype':'1:16:38 PM|A|1:16:38 PM',
    'PaxConfig':'1:16:38 PM|2|0|2|0||1:16:38 PM',
    'usid':'1:16:38 PM|henxvi3qegsrwqzewilkfp2m|1:16:38 PM'
```

At first glance, you already notice they are in patterns of:

```
$date|$param|$date
```

Where `$date` is current time in the format of `utc_ts_now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")`.

For `$param` section of these four parameters, I guess it should be fixed for `CallFrom` and `Btype`, `usid` is the **session** key, you can find it easily in the previous response.

`PaxConfig` is guest counts, it's related to `roomConfiguration` you sent in the first request.

To automate the second request, you would generate the decoded value for each parameter first, then encode them with `Base64`.

Update:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import base64
from datetime import datetime

import requests


def first_request(session, params):
    url = 'https://booking.discoverqatar.qa/SearchHandler.aspx'
    r = session.get(url, params=params)
    return r


def second_request(session, params):
    url = 'https://booking.discoverqatar.qa/PassengerDetails.aspx'
    r = session.get(url, params=params)
    return r


def main():
    params1 = {
        'Module':             'H',
        'txtCity':            '',
        'hdnCity':            '2947',
        'txtHotel':           '',
        'hdnHotel':           '',
        'fromDate':           '05/11/2019',
        'toDate':             '07/11/2019',
        'selZone':            '',
        'minSelPrice':        '',
        'maxSelPrice':        '',
        'roomConfiguration':  '2|0|',
        'noOfRooms':          '1',
        'hotelStandardArray': '63,60,54,50,52,51',
        'CallFrom':           '',
        'DllNationality':     '-1',
        'HdnNoOfRooms':       '-1',
        'SourceXid':          'MTEzNzg=',
        'mdx':                ''
    }
    session = requests.Session()
    _ = first_request(session, params1)
    asp_session = session.cookies.get("ASP.NET_SessionId")

    params2 = {
        # Could related to options "Available" / "On Request"
        "Btype":     "A",

        # Try out other guest counts to make sure
        "PaxConfig": params1["roomConfiguration"] * 2,

        "CallFrom": "B2C",
        "usid":     asp_session
    }
    date = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    for k, v in params2.items():
        v = "|".join([date, v, date])
        v = base64.b64encode(bytes(v, "utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
        params2[k] = v
    r = second_request(session, params2)
    print(r.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```